# get records having admission between two dates

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to get records from a table where admission date is in a range, so 'datebegin' and 'endate' are in Date type, admissiondate is in Date format too.

```
List clients =  session.createQuery("Select Id_Client from Contract contract where contract.admissiondate BETWEEN '"+ datebegin+"' and '"+endate+"'").list();
```

With my query i get this error:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: admissiondate of: bean.Contract [Select Id_Client from bean.Contract contract where contract.admissiondate BETWEEN 'Sat Feb 15 00:00:00 CET 2014' and 'Mon Mar 17 00:11:24 CET 2014']
```

And it said:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your query.

It should be `contract.admissiondate`

Answer (score 0):

try casting it?

List clients =  session.createQuery("Select Id_Client from Contract contract where contrat.admissiondate BETWEEN '"+ cast(datebegin as datetime)+"' and '"+ cast(endate as datetime)+"'").list();

Comment: i did, and it said: SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Answer (score 0):

You aliased your contract table but it was spelt incorrectly when getting the admissiondate columns. Try the below.

List clients = session.createQuery("Select Id_Client from Contract contract where contract.admissiondate BETWEEN '"+ cast(datebegin as datetime)+"' and '"+ cast(endate as datetime)+"'").list();